# Network Solutions domain name redirect is adding html headers

Tags: heroku

I have a domain name registered with Network Solutions, www.anoneo.com.

My domain is redirected to my hosted web site at Heroku, hollow-lightning-4249.herokuapp.com.

I am trying to set up my Google webmaster tools sitemap.xml functionality, and it is working perfectly, except that Network Solutions adds  headers to my sitemap.xml response.

To see exactly what I mean, check http://hollow-lightning-4249.herokuapp.com/sitemap.xml, and view source.

Next, check http://www.anoneo.com/sitemap.xml, and view source.

I called Network Solutions to see if there is any way to suppress the html headers that they are adding, and they say there is nothing they can do.

Do I need to move to a new domain registrar, or is there a way to fix this?  If I need to move to a new domain registrar, who is the best one for Heroku sites?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Off-topic: this is a site for programming questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using redirection and not DNS to point your domain to heroku. Network Solutions are not changing your XML files (or any other files). They only display a HTML document with a frame which shows your content hosted at heroku.

You should have a look whether there's a way to change DNS settings for your domain so you can set it up properly. Have a look at the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) in Heroku Dev Center.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed my registrar settings from redirect to point to new name servers, and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

*P.S. I hope this is not some kind of Anon joke.*

1. View source has nothing to do with the headers
2. There is nothing added to neither of the XMLs source
3. See below the real Headers:

**http://hollow-lightning-4249.herokuapp.com/sitemap.xml**

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Age: 0
Date: Sat, 14 Jul 2012 21:08:04 GMT
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09)
X-Content-Digest: 3459e2e4d7581d2b9c67c096724040b062d0857a
X-Rack-Cache: stale, valid, store
Connection: keep-alive
```

**http://www.anoneo.com/sitemap.xml**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Sun-ONE-Web-Server/6.1
Date: Sat, 14 Jul 2012 21:05:17 GMT
Content-type: text/html
Transfer-encoding: chunked
```

You are all set, no need to change Network Solutions